# External Images does not display when used in img tag

Tags: html

I have these strange image urls that if I call direct in browser, an image shows up but when I use it in an img tag no image shows up.

```
http://thetvdb.com/banners/_cache/fanart/original/248951-1.jpg
```

I'm sure I'm making some silly mistake. Here is simple code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://thetvdb.com/banners/_cache/fanart/original/248951-1.jpg" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Image may display when you first time load image in html but upon refreshing it will disappear.

Comment: Have you checked if that site allows framing their content? By loading the image from their server as you are, you are effectively stealing THEIR bandwidth, forcing them to pay for YOUR usage of their image.

Comment: Note, image displays in Chrome but not IE for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The TV DB [does not want](http://forums.thetvdb.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=8105&hilit=hotlinking) to use their bandwidth to display an image on your site.

> We don't allow any kind of hotlinking, you are only allowed to directly download the images and then use them as you see fit, you may not use us as a host.

They have taken steps to prevent you from doing this.

```
quentin@laptop:~ # curl -e http://example.com/ http://thetvdb.com/banners/_cache/fanart/original/248951-1.jpg
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presumably the Android App is not sending an HTTP referer header in the request.