# CakePHP some images don't display because of NetworkError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: cakephp, apache2, cakephp-2.1

I have a problem on my view. The problem is that some images on external server do not display. I check FireFox console and get the following message:

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://xxxxx.com/image.jpg"

Although I can view this image by typing directly http://xxxxx.com/image.jpg to URL or save the view as HTML and view it.

Did I do something wrong in configuration?

I use:

1. CakePHP 2.3.1
2. smarty 3.1.13
3. Apache 2.2.23
4. MySQL 5.3.30
5. CentOS 6.3

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are that images completely unrelated to you or do you have access to the server in order to see the permissions of the files?

Comment: That images is on remote server and unrelated to me.

Comment: Well, maybe that's the problem, some people don't like to be [hotlinked](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking). If you confirm that's not the case, you can update your question stating that's not the problem, so we can think of other reasons

Comment: sounds very much like the other site is (probably rightfully so) preventing you stealing their images, there's no cakephp in this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [External Images does not display when used in img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724630/external-images-does-not-display-when-used-in-img-tag)