# Accessing image url in img tag shows 403 forbidden

Tags: image, http-status-code-403

I have written a simple C# MVC web app, in one of the views I am accessing a image url from other website as follows

```
<img src="http://some.public.website/static/test.jpg?cache=1111111" /> //shows 403 forbidden error

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg" /> //works great
```

I can see an error 403 forbidden in chrome console. However when i copy the exact above image url (`http://some.public.website/static/test.jpg?cache=1111111`) and open it in other browser tab it shows me the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [External Images does not display when used in img tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724630/external-images-does-not-display-when-used-in-img-tag)